# CyberTracker application for Android or iPhone

Tags: android, crossover

I am trying to find the CyberTracker Android installation or any way to run the software on either OS X or Android phone or tablet. I tried opening the installation file from the http://www.cybertracker.org/software/getting-started page with Crossover: http://www.cybertracker.org/downloads/software/Crossover-for-CyberTracker.pdf but Crossover doesn't recognize any of the files within the installation folder. Did someone manage to install it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, managed to install and operate Cybertracker on Android.
You have to plug the android device into the PC by a USB port that recognises the device as a storage device, then just hit the install to device button in cybertracker